# Apply css rules on nested component in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a nested component SearchBar as a child of my Header. 
My component definition:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search-form',
  templateUrl: 'search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'search-form.component.css']
})
```

*search-form.component.html* is using the following directive inside:

```
<tag-input placeholder="Add tags ..." 
    [(model)]="tagsArray" 
    (tagsChanged)="onTagsChange($event)"
    (tagsAdded)="onTagsAdded($event)"
    (tagRemoved)="onTagRemoved($event)"
    [delimiterCode]="[32]"></tag-input>
```

and inside *search-form.component.html* I have the following rule:

```
.ng2-tag-input-field {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The CSS rules have no effect on the nested directive, unless I put the CSS inside Styles.css file. Why this isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 12):

You need to change  your component's `viewEncapsulation`.

```
import { ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search-form',
  templateUrl: 'search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'search-form.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Angular 2 comes with view encapsulation built in, which enables us to use `Shadow DOM`. There are three view encapsulation types:

**1) ViewEncapsulation.None** - No Shadow DOM at all. Therefore, also no style encapsulation.

**2) ViewEncapsulation.Emulated** - No Shadow DOM but style encapsulation emulation.

**3) ViewEncapsulation.Native** - Native Shadow DOM with all it’s goodness.

For more see [**VIEW ENCAPSULATION IN ANGULAR 2**](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

Comment: If I use ViewEncapsulation.None it breaks my imported (nested) class. I want to effect down the waterfall (the nested component) but not be effected from outside the host component.

Comment: @Yuvals I don't understand your case clearly, but I think the problem is in the view encapsulation. Try to read the article given above

Comment: I updated the explanation - the problem is that I can't effect from outside a directive with CSS rules, unless the rules are in global styles.css

Comment: This helped me, i had some parent css that i could not get to work on my child component.

.full-screen .info-box { height: 50vh; } 

Where my info-box was my child element. With "ViewEncapsulation.None", my info-box had its height set to 50vh.

Comment: @balslev Very glad for you